# Force WordPress to create image thumbnails

Tags: php, wordpress

Currently, lines 378 -380 of `media.php` contains this line:

```
// if the resulting image would be the same size or larger we don't want to resize it
if ( $new_w >= $orig_w && $new_h >= $orig_h && !$allow_resize)
    return false;
```

That obviously makes a lot of sense for a typical setup, but I'm working on a photography site where admin will be uploading very high-quality JPGs that are the right dimensions for the Large size thumbnail, but the image quality is too high for web use.

Essentially, I'd like WordPress to create a large thumbnail that's the same size as the original (which the core code prevents it from doing). I've seen a few solutions floated around, but they all involve replacing and destroying the original, which I don't want to do.

Any tips on where to start?

Comment: Essentially you are asking how to reduce the resolution of the image, correct?

Comment: Yes, but I'd like to use WordPress' built-in compression engine to do so, and I'd like it to be consistent with how it compresses all other JPG files. I'm currently calling large thumbnails in a custom function, but since they're not being created, it defaults to the uncompressed originals instead.

Answer (score 1):

Try this in your functions.php of your theme:

```
add_filter('image_resize_dimensions', 'filterCompress', 1, 6);

function filterCompress($foo, $orig_w, $orig_h, $dest_w, $dest_h, $crop) {
  if ( $orig_w == $dest_w && $orig_h == $dest_h ) {
        return array( 0, 0, 0, 0, (int) $orig_w, (int) $orig_h, (int) $orig_w, (int) $orig_h );
  }
  return null;
}
```

I did this based on WordPress 3.5.1, based on your question I'm assuming you are using a different version but it still might work.

Comment: Hi Peter, I'm on the latest stable version (3.5.1). Why do you assume I'm on an older version? Also, given that WordPress won't resize the Original if it's smaller than the Large thumbnail dimensions at all, will this function work?

Comment: Interestingly, that actually results in images that are larger in file size (same dimensions) than the original.

Comment: The line numbers you gave didn't correspond with mine. Interesting that it is larger. Can't check now, just got on the road, but will later.

Comment: Oh sorry... pulled those numbers from an older post. Thanks for your help!